# Meaning of Antlr4's LABEL_CONFLICTS_WITH_RULE

Tags: java, label, antlr4

I have a rule as

```
nls
    :   NL*
    ;
```

with lexer token

```
// Inside (...) and [...] but not {...}, ignore newlines.
NL  : '\r'? '\n'            { this.ignoreTokenInsideParens(); }
    ;
```

on compile, i get

```
antlr:
 [java] error(69): Pel.g4:19:86: label nls conflicts with rule with same name
```

My understanding is that labels are #names you give to alternative branches of a production. I have no such labels.

So, what does this error mean?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @BartKiers i looked at every nls use, and found i had an errant = sign where i had removed a variable assign in a rule, but missed the =, like

```
expression nls AND nls =expression
```

that was the issue.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have a rule called `nls`, but also [a label](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/parser-rules.md#alternative-labels) with that name:

```
nls
    :   NL*
    ;

...

rule
    : FOO BAR # nls
    ;
```

The `# nls` (or `#nls`) is the label.

Comment: yes that's what i assumed the error meant as well. I have no # labels at all in the grammar

Comment: @MeBigFatGuy if you do a CTRL+F on your grammar, there are no odd `nls` usages? You're not importing grammars with labels? if not, then you may have found a bug. You can report it here: https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues